# MySQL left join needed on Wordpress database

Tags: mysql, wordpress, left-join

I'm new to MySQL and ended up with this statement on a standard Wordpress database to get the latest articles.
However, the statement below requires that related rows are found in [wp_postmeta] to get the thumbnail belonging to the article.
However, some posts may not have a thumbnail but I still want to select those.

How can I alter the statement to not require a thumbnail value in [wp_postmeta]? I believe I need a `left join` clause, but don't know how to do it.

```
SELECT p.*, ( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value ) AS imgurl 
FROM wp_posts p, wp_postmeta m
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.id = m.post_id
AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with join and `ON(p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id' )`

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.*, ( SELECT guid FROM wp_posts WHERE id = m.meta_value LIMIT 1) AS imgurl 
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT JOIN  wp_postmeta m ON(p.id = m.post_id AND m.meta_key =  '_thumbnail_id' )
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
ORDER BY post_date DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this query it will fetch latest 5 post, you can increase the display limit.

```
 $sql = " SELECT * FROM wp_posts p
WHERE p.post_type =  'post'
AND p.post_status =  'publish'
AND p.post_type = 'post'
ORDER BY p.post_date DESC
LIMIT 5";
```